# Any way of getting the dictionary to store value rather than pointing to value?

Tags: c#, dictionary

So I have a dictionary:

```
var tableVars = new Dictionary<string, TableDLL.tableObject>();
```

And the tableObject class:

```
public class tableObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public string Default { get; set; }
    }
```

And I go through this loop:

```
var obj = new TableDLL.tableObject();
        foreach (XmlNode nodes in root.ChildNodes)
        {
            obj.Value = nodes.InnerText;
            tableVars.Add(nodes.Name, obj);
        }
```

When the loop is complete, I have 65 different `Dictionary` entries, but they are all pointing to the LAST `obj` that is made in the loop. What would be the best way to get the `Dictionary` to store the value, rather than simply pointing to it (and therefore changing with changes to `obj`)? Do I have to make a new `TableDLL.tableObject` for each `Dictionary` entry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're only creating a single object and continually updating `Value` with the last node.  With the correction, you're creating N objects with the appropriate `Value`.

This:

```
    var obj = new TableDLL.tableObject();
    foreach (XmlNode nodes in root.ChildNodes)
    {
        obj.Value = nodes.InnerText;
        tableVars.Add(nodes.Name, obj);
    }
```

should be this:

```
    foreach (XmlNode nodes in root.ChildNodes)
    {
        var obj = new TableDLL.tableObject();
        obj.Value = nodes.InnerText;
        tableVars.Add(nodes.Name, obj);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Move the creation of `obj` into the loop:

```
    foreach (XmlNode nodes in root.ChildNodes)
    {
        var obj = new TableDLL.tableObject();
        obj.Value = nodes.InnerText;
        tableVars.Add(nodes.Name, obj);
    }
```

Otherwise you are adding the *same* object multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to create it in the loop:

```
foreach (XmlNode nodes in root.ChildNodes)
{
    var obj = new TableDLL.tableObject();
    obj.Value = nodes.InnerText;
    tableVars.Add(nodes.Name, obj);
}
```

Otherwise you're always adding the same object.

Answer (score 2):

You've only created 1 object, so there is no possibility for the list to have 65 different objects.

Basically, what you did is:

1. Take a box.
2. Put something in the box.
3. Now replace that thing with another thing.

You haven't created a new container, you just changed the existing container's contents.

Do it like this:

```
    foreach (XmlNode nodes in root.ChildNodes)
    {
        var obj = new TableDLL.tableObject();
        obj.Value = nodes.InnerText;
        tableVars.Add(nodes.Name, obj);
    }
```

The difference being:

1. Take a box.
2. Put something in the box.
3. **Now take a new box.**
4. Put the other thing in the new box
5. etc...

If you want 65 `tableObject` objects, you will need to call `new tableObject();` 65 times. Else you're just reusing the original object.

Feel free to ask for more information if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new copy of your `tableObject` each time round the loop.

```
    foreach (XmlNode nodes in root.ChildNodes)
    {
        var obj = new TableDLL.tableObject();
        obj.Value = nodes.InnerText;
        tableVars.Add(nodes.Name, obj);
    }
```